# how do I loop a function for a list based on column name and row?

Tags: r, loops

I am still very new to R and this is the first time I am using the loop function.

I have a list with let's say 5 columns and 100 rows. I need to apply a binomial (0 for uninfected or 1 for infected) to only one column, and within this column the binomial need to be spread across different rows according to a percentage.So the rows with the value 15 have 0.1% chance of getting infected, those with value 16 have 0.5% and so on.
How do I do this? I am completely stuck!

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hello, please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].

Comment: In addition to Maël's comments, please edit your question to include a *minimal* reproducible dataset - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for tips on how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?
Use a named vector of probabilities and `match` to assign an index into the probabilities vector. Then, wherever there are matches (not `NA`), since `rbinom` is vectorized, compute all 0/1 in one instruction.

```r
# make up a test data set
set.seed(2023)
df1 <- iris[-1]
df1$col <- sample(c(15, 16, 1:5), 150, TRUE)

# the code starts here
new_values <- setNames(c(0.1, 0.5), c(15, 16))
df1$new_col <- match(df1$col, names(new_values))
i <- !is.na(df1$new_col)
df1$new_col[i] <- rbinom(sum(i), 1, prob = new_values[ df1$new_col[i] ])

head(df1, n = 10L)
#>    Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species col new_col
#> 1          3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa   3      NA
#> 2          3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa   5      NA
#> 3          3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa  15       0
#> 4          3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa   1      NA
#> 5          3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa  16       1
#> 6          3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa   2      NA
#> 7          3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa  16       0
#> 8          3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa  15       0
#> 9          2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa  15       1
#> 10         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa   3      NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>